# Retrieve total term frequency from Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin, inverted-index, elasticsearch-api

I am writing an Elasticsearch plugin, and in this plugin I need to retrieve the term frequency count from a specified in a certain field. At the moment I am using the query below, and reading the number of hits from the result:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = nodeClient
            .prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(TERM_FIELD, term))
            .get();
```

However, this needs to be done multiple times (10-20 times) and seems to be slow. Is there a way to use the Elasticsearch Java API and read data from the inverted indices directly?

In Lucene I used a function called `totalTermFreq()`, which reads the total number of occurences the term has across all documents directly from the inverted indices. Lucene's documentation of the function can be found [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html#totalTermFreq())

Comment: get the total terms and put them in In clause                                                           QueryBuilders.termsQuery("fname", term)

Comment: Do you mean I should do one `termsQuery` with all the terms instead?

Comment: Yes , put all the terms in terms query like [1,2,3]

Comment: QueryBuilders.termsQuery("fname", [1,2,3,4,5......]])